# Vimtex and latexmkrc config. Question about compiling

Tags: plugin-vimtex

I didn't understand very well this part, since English is not my native language.

```
LATEXMK                                               *vimtex-compiler-latexmk*

As stated, one may customize the `latexmk` options through
|g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk|.  However, one may also configure `latexmk`
explicitly through a global `~/.latexmkrc` file, or a project specific
`.latexmkrc` file. It is important to know that command line arguments have
priority, so one may want to use custom options if one wants to specify
particular things in a configuration file.
```

I do have a `latexmkrc` file with my settings. In `.vimrc` I have only

```
let g:vimtex_view_method = 'zathura'
let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'
```

*So every time I use `<leader>ll` will use my config file, or some other default config for `latexmk` hidden in the plugin's code?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration specified in your `.latexmkrc` file will be overridden by the command-line options passed to `latexmk` by VimTeX. The default options are, as specified in `:help g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk`:

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
    \ ...
    \ 'options' : [
    \   '-verbose',
    \   '-file-line-error',
    \   '-synctex=1',
    \   '-interaction=nonstopmode',
    \ ],
    \}
```

Thus, if you for instance used `-synctex=0` in your `.latexmkrc`, it would be overridden. But the default options are sensible, and I don't see why you would want to override them anyway.

> So every time I use `<leader>ll` will use my config file, or some other default config for latexmk hidden in the plugin's code?

You will use both, although there is really no hidden configuration in VimTeX. Everything is documented.

Comment: Ok. I understand now! Thanks for the plugin & for the info!